# how to create labels for asp.net chart?

Tags: asp.net, charts

how can I display labels for the asp.net chart? I attached a sample chart. How can I define the product A , B etc?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following example, the method you're looking for is callled - AddXY:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> employees = new Dictionary<int, string>();

            employees.Add(10, "Product A");
            employees.Add(20, "Product B");
            employees.Add(30, "Product C");

            Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> employee in employees)
            {
                Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(employee.Value, employee.Key);
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

[image: ASP.NET MS Chart control]